# Google Maps - Unable to draw Polygons and Linestrings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building an application using **MEAN Stack** and **Google Maps Api** and I'm having a little problem when it comes to draw **Polygons** and **LineStrings**.

I have a collection of geometries (Points, Polygons and LineStrings) and each time I find one of them I need to add it properly to the map.

I have no problem when it comes to render Markers but I have issues when it comes to Polygons and LineStrings.

Here's my code which contains the logic of initializing the map.

```
// Initializes the map
function initialize(latitude, longitude, filter) {

   // If map has not been created...
   if (!map) {
      // Create a new map and place in the index.html page
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 3,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(vm.selectedLat, vm.selectedLong)
               });
   }

   // Loop through each location in the array and place a geometry
   locations.forEach(function (n) {

            if(n.type === 'LineString'){

               console.log('LineString '+JSON.stringify(n.coords));
               var linestring = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                 position: n.coords,
                                 map: map,
                                 geodesic: true,
                                 strokeColor: '#0404B4',
                                 strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                 strokeWeight: 2
                                });

               // For each linestring created, add a listener
               google.maps.event.addListener(linestring, 'click', function () {
                  // When clicked, open the selected linestring's message
                  n.message.open(map, linestring);
                });

                linestring.setMap(map);
            }
            if(n.type === 'Polygon'){

               console.log('Polygon '+JSON.stringify(n.coords));
               var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                               path: n.coords,
                               geodesic: true,
                               strokeColor: '#0404B4',
                               strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                               strokeWeight: 3,
                               fillColor: '#0404B4',
                               fillOpacity: 0.35
                        });

                // For each polygon created, add a listener
                google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function () {
                    // When clicked, open the selected polygon's message
                    n.message.open(map, polygon);
                });

                polygon.setMap(map);
           }

  });
};
```

Here are the screenshots of the two `console.log()` of the coordinates

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot I also get
`InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`

I tried, unsuccessfully, to find a solution to that.

**Why can't I draw these geometries? How can I solve the InvalidValueError?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

- A `google.maps.Polyline` doesn't have a `position` property, it has a `path` property which takes an array of `google.maps.LatLngLiterals` (which looks like what you are passing in to the `position` property).
- A `google.maps.Polygon` has a `paths` property which takes an array of `google.maps.LatLngLiterals`, but your data is not formatted correctly (and you are using `path` not `paths`).  It is an array of `{lat: [46.774, -48.19], lng: [46.466, -29.119]}`, neither `lat` nor `lng` are Numbers, they are arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try that tomorrow and I'll let you know.